# How to parallelize this code with pthreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, knn

I am attempted to solve this assignment for class with pthreads. I have defined my struct, attempted to pass in the variables to my run2 section, but all it results with is segmentation fault core dumped. The code in there was originally in the KNN_POSIX2 method, but I have separated it out in preparation to make it multithreaded. I figured I would try with a single POSIX thread and see how it goes, but no dice thus far. I am brand new to C, so please be patient with me.

```
typedef struct PASSING_PARAMS2 {
    int* thread_identifier;
    ArffData* traindata;
    ArffData* testdata;
    int k;
    int tcount;
    int qIndex;
    int* parampred;
    int* paramclasscount;
    float* paramcandidates;
    int paramnumclasses;
} PassingParams2;

void* run2(void* ptr) {
    PassingParams2 *paramPtr = (PassingParams2 *)ptr;
    ArffData* train = (ArffData*)paramPtr->traindata;
    ArffData* test = (ArffData*)paramPtr->testdata;
    float* candidates = (float*)paramPtr->paramcandidates;
    int k = (int)paramPtr->k;
    int* classCounts = (int*)paramPtr->paramclasscount;
    int num_classes = (int) paramPtr->paramnumclasses;

    for(int queryIndex = 0; queryIndex < test->num_instances(); queryIndex++) {
        for(int keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < train->num_instances(); keyIndex++) {
            
            float dist = distance(test->get_instance(queryIndex), train->get_instance(keyIndex));

            // Add to our candidates
            for(int c = 0; c < k; c++){
                if(dist < candidates[2*c]){
                    // Found a new candidate
                    // Shift previous candidates down by one
                    for(int x = k-2; x >= c; x--) {
                        candidates[2*x+2] = candidates[2*x];
                        candidates[2*x+3] = candidates[2*x+1];
                    }
                    
                    // Set key vector as potential k NN
                    candidates[2*c] = dist;
                    candidates[2*c+1] = train->get_instance(keyIndex)->get(train->num_attributes() - 1)->operator float(); // class value

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Bincount the candidate labels and pick the most common
        for(int i = 0; i < k;i++){
            classCounts[(int)candidates[2*i+1]] += 1;
        }
        
        int max = -1;
        int max_index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_classes;i++){
            if(classCounts[i] > max){
                max = classCounts[i];
                max_index = i;
            }
        }

        predictions[queryIndex] = max_index;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2*k; i++){ candidates[i] = FLT_MAX; }
        memset(classCounts, 0, num_classes * sizeof(int));
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int* KNN_POSIX2(ArffData* train, ArffData* test, int k, int t) {

    // Predictions is the array where you have to return the class predicted (integer) for the test dataset instances
    int* predictions = (int*)malloc(test->num_instances() * sizeof(int));

    // Stores k-NN candidates for a query vector as a sorted 2d array. First element is inner product, second is class.
    float* candidates = (float*) calloc(k*2, sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*k; i++){ candidates[i] = FLT_MAX; }

    int num_classes = train->num_classes();

    // Stores bincounts of each class over the final set of candidate NN
    int* classCounts = (int*)calloc(num_classes, sizeof(int));
    
    //Setup of the parameters to be passed by the struct
    PassingParams2 *paramPtr;
    paramPtr = (PassingParams2 *) malloc(1* sizeof(PassingParams2));
    paramPtr->thread_identifier = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    paramPtr->traindata = train;
    paramPtr->k = k;
    paramPtr->tcount = t;
    paramPtr->paramnumclasses = num_classes;

    // create the threads
    pthread_t newthread;
    pthread_create(&newthread, NULL, &run2, (void*) paramPtr);

    return predictions;
}
```

Comment: IDK the answer, but it's not necessary to use the `&` operator to get a pointer to a function. Just the function name is enough. `&run2` and `run2` both mean exactly the same thing in the context where you used it, but `run2` is more typical of what other programmers write.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: It looks like all the `run` functions may have a shot at reading from the same `PassingParams2`. Consider what will happen if the main thread started all threads, passing them `paramPtr` but none of the threads actually start executing until after the last `pthread_create`. All thread would then read the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `run2(...)` function appears to use a free variable, `predictions`, as if it were an array of `int` or a pointer to an array of `int`. Where is `predictions` declared? Where is it `initialized`? It is *NOT* the same as the *local* variable, `predictions` that is declared and initialized in the `KNN_POSIX2(...)` function.

Is it possible that `predictions` is a global `int*` variable, and is it possible that you are using it uninitialized in `run2(...)`?

---

Also note: Your `KNN_POSIX2(...)` starts a new thread, and then it immediately returns a pointer to the `predictions` array that it allocated. Is that supposed to be the same array that `run2()` fills in?

If so, then how will the caller of `KNN_POSIX2()` know when the thread has finished filling it in?

Comment: Yes, the predictions array in KNN_POSIX2 is supposed to be filled in by run2. I'm not sure how to connect the two together.

Comment: @Raidriar, starting a new thread via `pthread_create()` does not cause the caller to wait for the thread to finish its work.  That would be pointless, because how then could you have multiple threads running at the same time?  It would be equivalent to an ordinary function call.  But you usually do want *at some point* to wait for your threads to complete their work.  This is what `pthread_join()` is for.

Comment: @Raidriar, Re, "I'm not sure how to connect the two together." Lots of ways to do that. One way would be to make both `predictions` and `newthread` be members of the `PASSING_PARAMS2` struct, and then change `KNN_POSIX2()` to return `paramPtr` to its caller. That way, the caller can `pthread_join(paramPtr‑>newthread)` before it tries to access the predictions; and then it can `free(paramPtr‑>thread_identifier)`, `free(paramPtr‑>predictions)`, and `free(paramPtr)` after it has finished its work.